# ImageMagick Convert BMP from 24 bit to 16 bit question?

Tags: imagemagick, bmp

Trying to convert bmp file from 24-bit to 16-bit bmp by **[ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php)** and **[ViX 統合画像ビュアー](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/ViX)**. This is the same as the thumbnail in my images, but in hex content is not my expected. And the question I ask because I have to covert these 16-bit bmp files to a .spr (Sprite image file) for MMORPG Game(Lineage 1).

- ImageMagickVersion: **ImageMagick-7.1.0-portable-Q16-HDRI-x64**
- ViX 統合画像ビュアー Version: **ViX 2.21**
- Plateform: **Win11**
- [Source fils here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1W57LCMc68HDqyYvXxpkOV-hzAbPx-k7j?usp=sharing)

  1. Input_24bit.bmp
  2. Output_16bit_ViX.bmp
  3. Output_16bit_IM.bmp

ImageMagick Command

```
convert '24_bit.bmp' -alpha off -define bmp:subtype=RGB565 '16_bit.bmp'
```

ViX 統合画像ビュアー

```
Use GUI windows to decreasing color to Highcolor(16bit)
```

Result presenting (Red background will been transparent in Game)
[image]


BMP Hex Compare

- (A) result from **ViX 統合画像ビュアー** that I expected
- (B) result from **Imagemagick convert**

[image]

Comment: If you would like folks to help you, it's often a good strategy to make it easy for them. Please be more helpful about what is different from your expectations and why. At the moment you are presenting two screenfuls of hex with no indication as to what the problem is. Thank you.

Comment: You seem to want to share an executable program - no sane person would run that! If you would like some help you need to share the 24-bit input image and the 16-bit BMP created by the ViX thing and the 16-bit BMP created by **ImageMagick**.

Comment: Update for source files with input and two output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that **ImageMagick**, by default, writes a v5 BMP, whereas your program has written a v3 BMP.

To make **ImageMagick** write the older BMP3 format, prefix your output filename with `BMP3:` like this:

```
convert input.bmp -alpha off -define bmp:subtype=RGB565 BMP3:output.bmp
```